# Running Bitcoind - prerequisites

Tags: bitcoind

Do I need to install the Bitcoin GUI and download the entire blockchain before being able to run bitcoind?
The instructions ask us to directly run bitcoind -daemon , will this start downloading the blockchain in the back end

https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#mac-os-x-yosemite-1010x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes bitcoind will download the entire blockchain so that it can work out what money is real.

You can enable pruning if you don't want to permanently store old blocks and don't want to help ensure the future security of Bitcoin.

You don't have to ever run bitcoin-qt